# Change property on a parent event

Tags: wpf, xaml, datatrigger

I'm trying to change a border property inside a button content when mouse is over the button itself.

This is not working for me and I'm wondering why, any help please?

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonGenericStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="35"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0.6"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#333"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"></Setter>
    </Style>

        <Style x:Key="AddButtonStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ButtonGenericStyle}" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Content">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Width="24" Margin="5,0,0,0" Source="/Images/AddNew.png"></Image>
                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Static local:GenericGridResources.AddButtonText}"></TextBlock>
                    <Border x:Name="borderAdorner" Grid.Column="2" Width="5" Background="#00C176">
                        <Border.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Border.Style>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Thanks

Edit: I already set the padding to 10 and change the alignment to center to ensure that my button had not been covered.

Also, I debugged throught a converter at the DataTrigger binding and value sended was the Button. Still Border background doesn't change.

***** I change in my post the AncestorType from Image to Button. I ended copying a bad code from many tests. People answering that the ancestorTyoe should be a parent are totally rightm thanks and apologies.**

Comment: You should perhaps set the Button's Template instead of its Content. Then move the DataTrigger to the Triggers collection of the ControlTemplate or the Style.

Comment: You're setting `Background="#00C176"` on the Border XAML. That will supersede anything the Style does to it. If you want the Style to be able to change the background, set the background only in the style. Remove the Background attribute, and insert this just before the Setters element: `<Setter Property="Background" Value="#00C176" />`. Secondly: To be an ancestor, a control must *contain* the child. The Image is not an ancestor of the Border. You want AncestorType=Button anyway.

Comment: Thta's it @EdPlunkett ! Implicit styles on my border are superseding the triggers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want mouse over the button to work then the ancestortype should be button:

```
 <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
```

As it is, there is a sibling of your border which is an image. Findancestor will be looking up the visual tree and the border is not a child of the image.

You will also need to ensure there is something hit testable inside or as the background when the user mouse-overs the button. I mention this because it's not totally clear what your ButtonGenericStyle does.